# Develop and run under different versions of Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework

It is possible to develop and test application under Play Framework 1.2.x/1.3.x and run it (for example as a module) in production-ready web-application written in Play Framework 2.x.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to run a Play 1.x application as module or similar 
under/within a Play 2.x project.
Play 2.x was completely rewritten from scratch - you could say it is a complete different framework with the same concepts as Play 1.x.

However you could let the apps communicate with each other (e.g. via webservices, a message system, etc.) However I think thats not a really good solution.

My recommendation is to just use the latest version of Play 2.x - Play 1.x is slowly dying, do not use it. Play 2 development is pushed forward whereas Play 1 hardly sees updates and new features. Also the Play 2 community is much more active. There are only one or two active committers to the Play 1 project - when they resign I guess no one will take care of the framework anymore. The Play 1 mailing list is basically dead too.